# VBA named range in Word?

Tags: vba, ms-word, doc

Is there a way to put invisible markers or id's in a document such that I can
get quick access to a fragment (paragrahp, table), in a way similar to the DIV/id combination used in HTML documents?

Yes, I can use bookmarks to point to a specific location in the document, but they do not the include the fragment itself, I'd be using two bookmarks, one to mark the start and the other for the end. Essentially what I'm looking for is a Word equivalent for named ranges as they are defined in Excel.

Any ideas?

Comment: Bookmarks can certainly include inline text & graphics - they aren't just "point locations".

Comment: Thank you bibadia, my last Word VBA application was back in 1996 and refers to a very outdated API. After reading your answer I found this link that explained what you said:
http://word.mvps.org/faqs/macrosvba/WorkWithBookmarks.htm